# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get this exception intermittently in my asp.net mvc 5 c# web application:

> Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

It just happens uploading images to S3 method (Web Api Controller).

The presendrequestheaders in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app != null &&
                app.Context != null)
            {
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            }
        }
```

The method that trigger the error:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadImageJSON")]
    public IHttpActionResult UploadImageJSON(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        // Check if files are available
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count != 1) return BadRequest();

        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];

        var contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
        if (!contentType.Contains("image"))
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
        }




        var keyUploadFiles = Constants.UrlS3Amazon +
                             S3.UploadToS3WithStream(postedFile.InputStream, contentType);


        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyUploadFiles));


    }
```

**EDIT:** More information... I have my Web App hosted in Elastic BeanStalk with a load balancer, the load balancer has installed a SSL Certificate, and the connection between the load balancer and the EC2 instances are in ports 80. Maybe it could be helpful.

The Elmah log:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
>      at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Thanks!!

Comment: It arrived each time you upload an image with your method ? Because you said at beginning that is an intermittent issue ...

Comment: Do you have any http modules that the response is passing through?

Comment: Your stack trace shows the code passes through `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler`. How is your authentication flow set up?

Comment: Good question. I'm seeing a similar, intermittent error that AFAICT has nothing to do with any of my code, but has the same stack replete with `Microsoft.Owin.Security` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` method calls. In my case "how is the flow set up?" is "how it came out of the AspNet.Identity box."

Comment: It seems like the exception is occurring in your UploadToS3WithStream method so you need to show the code for that method.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with removing  app.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server"); i think there is this is the issue?